# If $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, there exists $x$ so that both $E \cap (x, \infty)$ and $E \cap (-\infty,x)$ are uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Given $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, show that there exists $x$ so that both $E \cap (x, \infty)$ and $E \cap (-\infty,x)$ are uncountable.

A very simple statement that seems to be eluding me..

Here are my thoughts so far:

Let $$\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (-n,n).$$
Then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $E \cap (-N,N)$ is uncountable. Now, as an open interval, $$(-N,N) = \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} I_j$$ where $I_j \cap I_k = \emptyset$ for $j \neq k$.

Suppose no such $x$ exists.

Notice that one and only one of the sets $E \cap I_j$ is uncountable then, for if not, we would be able to find such an $x$. Call this set $I_{m_0}$.

As an open interval, $$I_{m_0} = \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} I_{j_0}.$$ Again, only one such $E \cap I_{j_0}$ can be uncountable call it $I_{m_1}$. Repeating this process indefinitely, we may write

$$E \cap [-N,N] = (\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} E \cap I_j \setminus E \cap I_{m_0}) \cup (\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} E \cap I_{j_0} \setminus E \cap I_{m_1}) \cup \ldots \cup (\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} E \cap I_{j_{k-1}} \setminus E \cap I_{m_k}) \cup \ldots $$

But notice that this is a countable union of countable sets. Ergo, a contradiction, so such an $x$ must exist.

Is this proof correct? Something seems awry.

I'd like to know
i) if this proof is valid.
ii) A better proof. Surely one exists.

Comment: The big problem is that you can’t write $(-N,N)$ as the union of countably infinitely many pairwise disjoint non-empty open intervals: such a union is never an interval. [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/412625/12042) to an earlier question gives a proof of the desired result (and in fact of a *much* stronger one).

Comment: I’ve sketched one in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SKETCH: Let $$L=\{x\in\Bbb R:(\leftarrow,x)\cap E\text{ is countable}\}$$ and $$R=\{x\in\Bbb R:(x,\to)\cap E\text{ is countable}\}\;.$$

We want to show that $L\cup R\subsetneqq\Bbb R$. Suppose that $L\cup R=\Bbb R$.

- Use the fact that $\Bbb R=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}(\leftarrow,n)$ to show that $R\ne\varnothing$.
- Use a similar idea to show that $L\ne\varnothing$.
- Show that if $x\in L$ and $y\in R$, then $x<y$. Conclude that $\sup L$ and $\inf R$ exist.
- Use an idea like that of the first point to show that $\sup L\in L$.
- Conclude similarly that $\inf R\in R$.
- Use the observation that $L\cap R=\varnothing$ to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Why do $R$ and $L$ need be non-empty? Again, if $E$ is the set of irrationals, no such $x$ exists unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: If $E=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, then **every** $x\in\Bbb R$ works.

Comment: If $R=\varnothing$, then $n\in L$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$, so $(\leftarrow,n)\cap E$ is countable for every $n\in\Bbb N$. But then $E$ is countable (why?), a contradiction.

Comment: A suitable $x$ so that the statement holds, yes of course. I mean what $y$ exists so that $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \cap (y,\infty)$ is countable

Comment: I believe I'm confused as to why both $R$ and $L$ can't be empty.

Comment: @Anthony: Sorry: you’re quite right. I just realized that I inadvertently failed to write down an assumption, namely, that $R\cup L=\Bbb R$; I was intending the argument to be by contradiction and forgot to say so. I’ve fixed it; see if it makes sense now.

Comment: Ah I see how this works now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Anthony: You’re welcome. Sorry again about the initial confusion.